# Show Div on image click in js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

what I am trying to achieve, is to create a clickable image, that shows a div. The catch is that you can only click to show the div, but not to hide it again. If you click some other image, the div will be replaced by another one.

I have managed to do this with this line of code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("popis").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("popis").innerHTML = "text";
}

function myFunction3() {
  document.getElementById("popis").innerHTML = "Nejaky text ";
}
```

```css
img {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1495916678star-png-red-small-alpha-transparent-image-clip-art.png" onclick="myFunction()"></button>
<img src="https://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1495916678star-png-red-small-alpha-transparent-image-clip-art.png" onclick="myFunction2()"></button>
<img src="https://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1495916678star-png-red-small-alpha-transparent-image-clip-art.png" onclick="myFunction3()"></button>
<div id="popis"></div>
```

So what this does, it shows different text on image click. I didn't get it working with divs thou. I want to be able to place heading and text paragraphs into divs, not just paragraph alone.Therefore, I would like to have one div displayed by default and changed when clicing on other image.

Afterwards I have to add this to wordpress, but I got images and div section, so I guess this code is pretty straightforward.

Also, it is possible to use toogle or array here, but I have been unable to get it working using those lately. I got some result with these approach at least.

Comment: Here's how to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/d13nm2hb/ You can put whatever you want inside the three divs.

Comment: @ChrisG as OP said when you click on the same image that div must dissapear

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I read OP's `The catch is that you can only click to show the div, but not to hide it again.` as something they want to achieve; the only issue OP has is to show HTML instead of plain text

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. There is one more point to this, how do I make one of those divs to display by default ? Lets say there will be image 1 and div 1 always displayed when you visit the web.

Comment: I updated the fiddle :)

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you, I ll let you know how it works

Answer (score 0):

It may be in your best interest to make separate div's for each set of data you want to display. You can set a CSS rule on your dynamic divs to make them `display: none;` by default. Then you can simply `document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";` when it is time to show them. Or `$('myDiv').show();` with jQuery.

Comment: Using `id`s implies duplicate code, and using jQuery in a wordpress environment requires using `jQuery` instead of `$`.